# Concatenation problem in Dynamic sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to concatenate the string with multiple variables and go for exec. Unfortunately I'm facing the conversion problem as:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Select @ExistingIds= CBSE_IX_J from ##tempPivot where EmployeeID=' to data type int.

My query is :

```
SET @ExecColumn = concat('Select @ExistingIds= '+@TSectionName +' from ##tempPivot where EmployeeID='+CAST(@TUserID as INT),'')
PRINT @ExecColumn
EXEC (@ExecColumn)
```

Comment: `CAST(@TUserID as INT)` => `CAST(@TUserID as VARCHAR(20)`. Beside of that it is not clear why the `CONCAT()` was used in your snippet

Comment: What's the point of this query? There's no reason to use string concatenation for @TUserID. Executing this query will fail too, because parameters and variables must be defined in the scope they are used - the query itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "simple" answer is **don't** concatenate **raw** string values into your dynamic statement, and **parametrise** your code. This is a *bit* of guesswork, however, is far safer than the SQL Injection hole you have right now:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'SELECT @ExistingIDs = ' + QUOTENAME(@TSectionName) + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)+
           N'FROM ##tempPivot' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'WHERE EmployeeID = @TUserID;';
PRINT @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
                   N'@TUserID int, @ExistingIds int OUTPUT', --guessed datatypes and that @ExistingIds is an OUTPUT
                   @TUserID = @TUserID,
                   @ExistingIds = ExistingIds OUTPUT;
```

*Note: the fact that your variable is called `@ExistingIDs` **implies** you want to store multiple values in that variable. `@ExistingIDs` is a scalar value, it will only hold a scalar (single) value. If the query above returns multiple rows, only the value of from the last row will be returned. For example:*

```
DECLARE @i int;
SELECT @i = I
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9))V(I)
ORDER BY I;
SELECT @i;
```

*Notice that `@i` has the value `9`, not `'1,2,3,...,9'`.*

Answer (score 1):

You would seem to want:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
DECALRE @ExistingIds NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'
SELECT @ExistingIDs = STRING_AGG(@TSectionName, '''')
FROM ##tempPivot
WHERE EmployeeID = @TUserID
';

-- Cannot have identifiers as parameters, so use `REPLACE()`
SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '@TSectionName', QUOTENAME(@TSectionName);

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
                   N'@TUserID int, @ExistingIds NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', --guessed datatypes and that @ExistingIds is an OUTPUT
                   @TUserID=@TUserID,
                   @ExistingIds=@ExistingIds OUTPUT;
```

In older versions of SQL Server, you need another approach for concatenating strings.  For instance

```
SET @SQL = N'
SELECT @ExistingIDs = (SELECT @TSectionName
                       FROM ##tempPivot
                       WHERE EmployeeID = @TUserID
                       FOR XML PATH ('')
                      )
';
```